# Insert Into Select with Two Select Statement's from the same Table with Inner Select Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO Training
( 
     TrainingID
    ,EmployeeID 
    ,TrainingEmployeeStatusID
    ,TrainingSessionID
    ,DepartmentID
    ,LastModified
    ,RevisionNum
) 

SELECT        
       (SELECT TrainingID from TrainingGlobal.TrainingInformation
        WHERE TrainingDesc = 'A First Value') 
      , FirmEmployeeID
      , 5
      , TrainingSessionID
      , DepartmentID
      , GETDATE()
      , 1

UNION ALL SELECT        
       (SELECT TrainingID from TrainingGlobal.TrainingInformation
        WHERE TrainingDesc = 'Another Value') 
      , FirmEmployeeID
      , 5
      , TrainingSessionID
      , DepartmentID
      , GETDATE()
      , 1


   From #ATempTable
        WHERE DepartmentID IN ( SELECT DepartmentID from TrainingGlobal.DepartmentIDs) 
        AND   FirmEmployeeID IN (SELECT EmployeeID from TrainingGlobal.EmployeeIDS)
```

My question is if it is possible to have two select statements on an Insert Into where the select statements are selecting from the same table, but changing the condition of an inner select on each new one.

As in the first line of each select statement would have a different condition for the WHERE clause, but the information is all coming from one temporary table.

I'm using MS-SQL 2016

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JOIN` would seem to be simpler:

```
SELECT ti.TrainingInformation
      FirmEmployeeID,
      (CASE WHEN ti.TrainingDesc = 'A First Value' THEN 5 ELSE 6 END),
      TrainingSessionID, DepartmentID, GETDATE(), 1
FROM #ATempTable a CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT ti.*
      FROM Training.TrainingInformation ti
      WHERE TrainingDesc IN ('A First Value', 'Another Value')
     ) ti;
```

Comment: You missed that he wants TrainingEmployeeStatusID to change to either 5 or 6 based on the grouping.

Comment: Actually that TrainingEmployeeStatus does not need to change. I will edit the question. The only thing that needs to change is the TrainingID based on the TrainingDesc. I will update with more complete code

Comment: In that case, use Gordon's unedited code.  Using a Join is better than using a Union.